# is it possible for hibernate to create a column in db with default value if it is declared in the domain class?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails

I need do add a column in the database with **false** value for all the records in a table(more than 5 millions rows). I've declared the column in the domain class :`boolean isLocked`, but when the application starts, I receive this exception:  `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column isLocked does not exist`.

I want to know if I can make hibernate create this column only once with the default value (false for boolean).

I am using grails 3.3.9 version.

Comment: There are at least 2 issues to address.  Is your `dataSource` configured to enable Hibernate to do schema generation and if so, what is the value you have assigned to `dbCreate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done eventually was to create the column in the database by hand, so when starting the app, it will see that the column exists in the db.